# How to get the current user in .net core web api post request?

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, webapi, .net-core-3.1

I'm working on an angular project which uses http and web api(.net core 3.1) to connect with Data base which is registered and deployed in Azure and I have given access to only one user currently in Azure active directory and in the post request I want to get that current user who is saving/editing the record. I have tried using MSAL but the sessonstorage.getitem() is empty. and I'm new to MSAL so please tell me how it works and I would be grateful if someone explains step by step on using MSAL and getting the current user. can you please help me with this? Thanks in Advance!!

Note If there is another way of getting the current user(not by windows authentication) who has given access in Azure active directory in .net core 3.1 please tell me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa) using MSAL. It shows the welcome message with `myMSALObj.getAccount()` after signing in.

```
const myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

function signIn() {
  myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest)
    .then(loginResponse => {
      console.log('id_token acquired at: ' + new Date().toString());
      console.log(loginResponse);

      if (myMSALObj.getAccount()) {
        showWelcomeMessage(myMSALObj.getAccount());
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

function showWelcomeMessage(account) {

    // Reconfiguring DOM elements
    cardDiv.classList.remove('d-none');
    welcomeDiv.innerHTML = `Welcome ${account.name}`;
    signInButton.classList.add('d-none');
    signOutButton.classList.remove('d-none');
}
```